# Debug multiple browser at once

Tags: debugging, browser

Is there a tool available that can offer multiple browsers debugging at once? Or just a tool that can debug on all browser but seperately.

Using each of browsers debug tools seperately is time consuming and confusing because tools are different?

Comment: The answer is no, there is not. Welcome to web development, you should have been here before browsers had no debugging console. :)

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to make a code validated by the W3C validator.
therefor, the navigators won't have to fix errors, and it will simply read everywhere the same